# Is there a smartphone app for mobile asset logging?

Tags: remote-sensing, software-recommendations, mobile

I'm after a recommendation for a smartphone app (iPhone or Android) to log asset information for litter bins. I need the following features

- GPS
- geotagged photos
- Form with drop down menus for user definable attributes, e.g. construction material,classification, condition etc
- export to csv or shp

Comment: Are there also any similar applications for Windows Mobile?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, in addition to logging points and attributing, I am also interested in attributing GPS tracks.

Comment: Short paper [Mobile Solutions for GIS Data Collection and Display](https://sites.google.com/site/dougbrowningportfolio/Resources/mobile-gis) by Doug Browning might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Geopaparazzi is interesting for you: http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/

The main features available in Geopaparazzi are:

- georeferenced notes
- georeferenced and orientated pictures
- gps tracks logging
- easy export of collected data
- a map view for the navigation of the environment

Answer (score 2):

Field Assets is a nice app for this:
http://www.fieldassetsapp.com/FieldAssets.html

Answer (score 2):

For android or iphone you can also try [epicollect](http://www.epicollect.net/) - while it doesn't have export to csv or shape built in- it does synchronise with a server-based database, so you can export your data from that in whatever format you want.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenDataKit application for Android is coming along nicely http://opendatakit.org/.

For Windows Mobile there is a standard application for ArcGIS Mobile, but it requires a licensed ArcGIS Server http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgismobile/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Post is kinda old but... I was looking for this lately and found doForms (www.doforms.com).
Free for one handheld.
Able to build your own forms for data collection.  Make your form, collect GPS, geotagged pics, videos, even barcode numbers.  Export to table.  Very easy to use too.
Probably others?

I don't think it has a built in map/GIS.... but I simply used Google maps while I fiddled with it.

edit>>> Just looked at OpenDataKit from above... looks exactly like doforms, interesting.
FieldAssets' site states Android version under development.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, uses Geosetter
http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Creating_geo-referenced_photos_for_display_in_QGIS

a very attractive pathway for getting simplistic data in front of senior management is to use the output in Google Earth......

Answer (score 1):

a little late to the party, but may I suggest pcMapper for Android!

See http://www.novaspatial.com/

it let's you import/export ESRI shapefiles and edit both geometry and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

- GIS Cloud's [Mobile Data Collection](http://www.giscloud.com/features/mobile-data-collection) for iOS and Android (docs [here](http://www.giscloud.com/docs/eng/documentation/mobile_data_collection/)).

[image]

[image]

- [AntiMap](http://theantimap.com/) - newcomer to the market, accompanied by desktop package that can synchronize with video.

[image]