# Seeking Mobile Data collection software recommendations?

Tags: gps, mobile, data-collection

What [COTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) software is available to do mobile data collection, with GPS positioning.  Map display not required. I'm looking across the board (platform wise).

I'm already aware of...

- [RhinoSpect](http://rhinospect.com/)
- [ArcPad](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcpad/index.html)
- [ArcGIS Mobile](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgismobile/index.html)
- [Field Assets](http://www.fieldassetsapp.com/FieldAssets.html)
- [Retriever](http://www.retrievercommunications.com/)
- [Geopaparazzi](https://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/)
- [EpiCollect](http://www.epicollect.net/)
- [Trimble Field Inspector](http://www.trimble.com/fieldinspector.shtml)
- [iGIS](http://www.geometryit.com/igis/)

Any others you're aware of?

Answer (score 5):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

Some of the tools discussed in [an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12513) to [Seeking Mobile GIS applications for Android Tablets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452) would apply here, especially:

- GIS Cloud's [**Mobile Data Collection**](http://www.giscloud.com/features/mobile-data-collection)
- [**AntiMap**](http://theantimap.com)
- [**Funf Journal**](http://funf.media.mit.edu/gettingstarted.html#funf_journal_app)
- **[OpenPaths](https://openpaths.cc/)**

---

NextGIS Mobile [http://nextgis.com/nextgis-mobile/](http://nextgis.ru/en/nextgis-mobile/)

NextGIS Mobile is an open-source mobile GIS for Android which allows to create, edit and export geodata both online and offline.

[image]

NextGIS Mobile allows to:

- show multi-layer map (layers can come from online and offline sources);
- change visibility and layers order;
- navigate the map (panning, zoom in, zoom out);
- collect data in the field;
- edit vector data (both geometries and attributes) online and offline;
- record tracks;
- show coordinates, speed, elevation etc.

---

You might want to add [CyberTracker](http://www.cybertracker.org/software/introduction) to your list.

> CyberTracker is the most efficient method of field data collection.
> You can use CyberTracker on a Smartphone or handheld computer to
> record any type of observation. CyberTracker, which requires no
> programming skills, allows you to customize an Application for your
> own data collection needs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Only supports PalmOS, PocketPC and Windows Mobile devices right now thought. Since January 2013, it's working on Android devices too.

---

**QField for QGIS** [http://qfield.org](http://qfield.org/)
[image: Geometry digitizing]
[image: Attribute fields with images]

QField is the perfect companion of QGIS. The off-the-shelf application allows intuitive viewing and editing of data. With a slick user interface, QField allows using QGIS projects on tablets. QField’s map display is powered by the QGIS rendering engine, so the results are identical and come with the full range of styling possibilities available on the desktop. Editing forms on QField respect the QGIS configuration and are adapted for touch interaction. For situations where network access is unavailable, a QGIS plugin downloads all the data to the device and allows integrating the changes back when returning to the office. Features such as satellite positioning or camera integration make QField a powerful tool for those who need to edit on the go and would like to avoid standing in the swamp with a laptop or paper charts. For cases where an off-the-shelf solution is not enough, the core components of QField have been extracted into a new framework called QgisQuick. While QField covers the majority of use cases as an off-the-shelf solution, this framework can be used for custom development to meet specific customer requirements and workflows. QField, like QGIS, is an open source project. Everyone is welcome to contribute to make the product even better - whether it is with financial support, enthusiastic programming or visionary ideas.

---

**Mergin Maps** [https://merginmaps.com/](https://merginmaps.com)
[image: Mergin Maps: QGIS in your pocket]
Capture geo-info easily through your mobile/tablet with the Mergin Maps Input app. It is an open-source mobile GIS for Android, iOS and Windows, designed to be compatible with all mobile devices - even those with small screens. Mergin Maps Input App is based on QGIS libraries. It has native integration of [Mergin Maps Cloud Service](https://merginmaps.com). Mergin Maps is a geo-data ecosystem for collaborative work, capable of merging, versioning and easy transfer your geospatial data between mobile, cloud and QGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

GeoODK provides a way to collect and store geo-referenced information, along with a suite of tools to visualize, analyze and manipulate ground data for specific needs. It enables an understanding of the data for decision-making, research, business, disaster management, agriculture and more. As a multi-dimensional application, GeoODK’s goal is to provide an open source platform that can be expanded to address current and future needs of data collection.

http://geoodk.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try MapIt - excellent tool for spatial data collection.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osedok.gisdatacollector.

More detail can be found here: [http://mapit-gis.com](http://mapit-gis.com/)

[image]
[image]

- Mobile asset collection & management
- Survey layers (point, line, polygon)
- Attributes management
- Google Maps, Bing Maps, Open Street Map base maps
- Offline maps and Mapbox maps
- Export , Import, Share (CSV, KML, geojson, arcjson)
- Modern and easy to use interface
- Measurement of the area, perimeter and distance
- Support for multiple measurement units
- Support for number of local coordinate's systems

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [CommCare](http://www.commcarehq.org). CommCare is designed to give organizations the flexibility of building mobile apps tailored to their programs. This can include data collection, client registration and tracking, behavior change counseling, and much more. CommCare supports complex workflows, longitudinal client tracking, multimedia optimization for low-literate users, Java and Android platform support, offline usage, and integrated SMS for performance improvement, all with an online application builder designed for non-programmers.  Over 300 organizations ranging from the UN to grassroots groups in 50+ countries have used CommCare, making it the most widely adopted mobile platform for FLWs in emerging markets.

CommCare is developed by [Dimagi](http://www.dimagi.com) a social enterprise founded in 2002 that specializes in building and deploying mobile applications. Organizations can choose to build mobile apps on their own, or hire Dimagi’s globally based staff for project design and implementation support.

Answer (score 0):

http://ushahidi.com/
And these answers should all be converted into a community wiki

See also
[Is there a smartphone app for mobile asset logging?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/is-there-a-smartphone-app-for-mobile-asset-logging)

Answer (score 0):

Fulcrum is a cost-effective and customizable GIS mobile data collection platform. Includes a 30-day trial at sign up!

http://fulcrumapp.com/

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spatialnetworks.fulcrum&hl=en

[image]

Answer (score -1):

More to inform people which can be interested, here: [carnet-terrain-electronique](http://carnet-terrain-electronique.fr), a website devoted to mobile data collection, especialy for environmental data, avec some links for devices, apps, advices... don't hesitate to propose more things.

Unfortunately, this website is in french but it has a GTranslate module.

Answer (score -1):

MapItFast from AgTerra Technologies (www.agterra.com) is worth a look.  The product only works on Android devices at this time but they offer real time mapping, attribution with electronic forms, and sync to a private cloud account.  It works with or without a data connection in the field.  Basemaps, custom layers and export to shapefile, KMZ, and GPX is included.  Good way for field workers to gather spatial data for GIS professionals and it could be used as a low cost asset management system.

Answer (score -1):

The AQUASURVEY app is a new piece of software designed to help you collect your own data and organise your field campaigns.
It brings you through all the necessary steps to collect your own data: from the design of the survey to the concrete collection of data using several mobile devices, and integrates the data collected to allow for their use in GIS or statistical software applications.
The main added value is that this process does not necessarily need an Internet connection - the app includes several offline options so that you can overcome Internet connection problems during your field campaign.
This tool allows you to monitor and geo-reference your ongoing survey, and to integrate data collected by different surveyors.
It can also produce customised graphs and statistics, which can provide an overview of your dataset in a printable report.
The AQUASURVEY app consists of an easy-to-use application with one component for use by desktops and one for Android devices, with the optional integration of the online GIS on www.aquaknow.net.
This open-source application, developed by the European Commission’s Joint Research Centre and EuropeAid, is free of charge.

http://www.aquaknow.net/en/aquasurvey-software