# Seeking Mobile GIS applications for Android Tablets?

Tags: software-recommendations, android, mobile-gis

I know that [ArcGIS is available for Android](http://www.esri.com/landing-pages/software/mobile/arcgis-for-android), but does anyone know of any other GIS apps that are available for Android tablets?

Answer (score 34):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

- [**GPSLogger for Android**](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger) is a lightweight GPS logger with lots of useful tweaks [control over time/distance of logs, OSM integration, auto email of tracks, and easy on your battery].
- [**EpiCollect**](http://www.epicollect.net/) developed at Imperial College London together with web based management tools looks as really good option for data collection (more info [here](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0006968)).
- [**Open Data Kit**](http://opendatakit.org/) (ODK) also looks very promising on data collection front. [Check](http://opendatakit.org/2011/07/using-odk-with-postgis-geoserver-and-leaflet/) for instance ODK, GeoServer, Leaflet combo.
- [**AntiMap**](http://theantimap.com/) - was newcomer to the market, accompanied by desktop package that can synchronize with video. Currently it's website is unresponsive.
- [**Funf Journal**](http://www.funf.org/journal.html) - part of [Funf Open Sensing Framework](http://www.funf.org/index.html) developed by MIT Media Lab
- GIS Cloud's **[Mobile Data Collection](http://www.giscloud.com/features/mobile-data-collection)** for Android. Another data collection tool.
- **[OpenPaths](https://openpaths.cc/)** - yet another data collection option from New York Times Company
- [Input App: QGIS in your pocket](https://inputapp.io/en/) - Free and open source iOS/Android app designed to streamline the whole process behind geo-surveys by [Lutra Contsulting Ltd.](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk)
- **[QField for QGIS](http://qfield.org)** (Former QGIS on Android) is a very active project and is now at version 1.0:
- Blog: http://opengis.ch/
- From an [answer deleted for recommending the same software](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/64265/115) as this one:

> I like QGIS for android as it accepts both esri shape files and
> mapinfo tab files, and you can do thematic mapping as well as
> displaying geotiffs. You can edit shape files easily and use the built
> in gps if you have one, however it crashes my tablet if you are not
> located within the bounds of the map. Otherwise it is excellent and
> the devs are working on python compatibility meaning you will be able
> to use google and bing maps as well as open streets etc.
>
> The main issues are that the gui is designed for  a standard screen
> and all the buttons and icons are tiny on anything smaller than a 10"
> screen.
>
> For basic navigation and data entry on a custom map, i was using
> avenzas' pdf maps on iOs, which imports geo-registered PDFs. They have
> a beta for android which I haven't used but am planning on trialling.
> you can make geo-registered pdfs in mapinfo or arcmap.

---

So far I have settled on collecting KML based vector data with limited attribution.

Apps I have used:

1. Locus (free and paid version) https://market.android.com/details?id=menion.android.locus&feature=related_apps
2. OruxMaps https://market.android.com/details?id=com.orux.oruxmaps
3. Google Tracks (pre-installed on my phone)

Locus and Orux allow connecting to WMS services, Google/Bing, etc... I believe there is a separate add-on to allow Google maps in Locus.

---

I came across this interesting application that looks (have not used it) interesting for collection of data.

http://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/

Some more info:

Geopaparazzi is a tool developed to do very fast qualitative engineering/geologic surveys. Even if the main aim is in the field of surveying, it contains tools that can be of great use also to OpenStreetMappers as well as tourists that want to keep a geo-diary. Geopaparazzi is available on the Android Market.

To get started jump into the documentation section: https://code.google.com/p/geopaparazzi/wiki/Docs

The main aim of Geopaparazzi is to have a tool that:

- fits in any pocket and can be always at hand, when needed
- gives the possibility to take georeferenced and possibly orientated pictures during the survey, with further possibility to import them into the main GIS application BeeGIS
- is able to exploit easily internet connection, if available.
- is extremely easy to use and intuitive, providing just few important functionalities.

The main features available in Geopaparazzi are:

- georeferenced notes
- georeferenced and orientated pictures
- gps tracks logging
- easy export of collected data
- a map view for the navigation of the environment

This recent presentation might give more insight: http://www.slideshare.net/moovida/geopaparazzi-state-of-the-art

---

We develop a mobile GIS solution for Android tablets called **Mappt**, which has a free trial available from the Google Play store.  The trial version allows you access to all functionality of the software, with the exception that you can not export your data.

You can grab the trial for free from the Google Play Store:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.mappt

With Mappt, you can:

- Capture and work with your vector data offline.
- Import and export in Shapefile and KML formats.
- Work with WGS84 and UTM-based Coordinate Reference Systems.
- Import directly from Google Drive and export to email.
- Import your own large imagery, fully available offline, via the ArcGIS Compact Cache Bundle format.  We are also actively implementing other options to import imagery.
- Record GPS paths.
- Define geofences, with audible and visual alerts.

See the Mappt website for further information: [www.mappt.com.au](http://www.mappt.com.au/)

[image: Mappt sample image]

[image: Image showing ability to edit attributes]

---

Fulcrum is a cost-effective and customizable GIS mobile data collection platform. Includes a 30-day trial at sign up!

http://fulcrumapp.com/

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spatialnetworks.fulcrum&hl=en

[image]

---

I'm working on this and I have just published a GIS application: ItacaMap for Android ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itacasoft.itacamap ). At the moment you can see basic functionality (zoom, pan, view info, browse, select by rectangle, etc.), but I have already implemented edit functionalities (at least on the server side) and more is cooking.

---

[**Geospago**](http://www.geospago.com) is a new application.  It is a software-as-a-solution (SaaS) because it has a mobile application working in conjunction with a web application.  Both may be used for collecting/inputting data, editing/updating data, viewing/sharing data, and importing/exporting data.  The web portal runs on amazon with geoserver and syncs with the android app, which uses SQLite.

The web portal is used to invite/manage users, control user access to projects, create projects and custom forms, deploy the forms to users, and manage data.  It can import SHP & CSV files for data maintenance workflows.  It can export data to the standard formats (CSV, KML, SHP), but aslo provides feeds and an API.  This allows users to add a WFS feed to ArcMap or QGIS to see the data live from the cloud, a network link to Google Earth, or create your own script to pull the data through API requests to integrate with other systems.  Collecting data is easy as well as quickly getting new or updated data back into a enterprise system of record.  Geospago is the only app I have seen so far that provides this.

The mobile app is used to collect, view, and edit data (point, line, and polygon).  It runs on both phones and tablets.  It handles connected and disconnected environments through the use of mbtiles.  It allows multiple photos to be attached to a single record.  It also has barcode scanning and signature capabilities.  Synchronization is set to user specified intervals or can be manually forced.  This prevents overlap and duplication if you have multiple people collecting data for the same projects in connected areas.

Geospago is very affordable and available on a monthly, per-license pricing model that it can be frozen between projects or cancel-at-any-time basis so you can use it only when you need it.  Data is secure on Amazon cloud and can be download it at any time.

The Geospago website has more information and has a sign up link.  The website also has a link to the mobile app on the Google Play Store.

---

Found an app called MapItFast that is easy to use.  A free version that lets you gather point, line, polygon features and even photos.  I've used it for its basemaps and to calculate distance and area.  Unfortunately, the data stays on the device (no way to export or share..that I can find) without upgrading to the cloud services.  But that looks interesting since data can be exported to CSV, GPX, SHP and KMZ, it has built in synchronization to collaborate on mapping and location, full attribution, editing, and probably a bunch of other stuff I don't know about yet.  Might be useful to those folks doing group mapping on an Android and wanting a way to get it into Google Maps or ArcGIS.  I like the idea of a low cost Internet Map Server and tools.

Their website (http://www.mapitfast.com) has YouTube video.  I downloaded from Google Play.  Found the brochure online:
http://www.mapitfast.com/Documents/MIF_Brochure_2013.pdf

Comment: The pictures seem useful here but do you think you could shrink them?  It's a bit overwhelming.

Comment: I think we should dispense with the pictures in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also for a full featured GIS platform take a look at Field Tracer by DirtTech.com

You can get a demo at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dirttech.fieldtracer

Field Tracer is an application designed for simple GPS/GIS (geographic information system) mapping. Field Tracer requires no external hardware for basic operation; in the future for higher accuracy GPS mapping the program will connect to external GPS antennas using our RS-232 to Bluetooth converter. For example, a John Deere RTK globe could be used for sub-inch accuracy.
Field Tracer delivers efficiency improvements and cost-savings at every stage of your operation. It works on readily available and easily affordable hardware in a variety of sizes and specifications to meet your needs. Another advantage is the use of Dropbox as a platform for storing and accessing data. This means anytime access to your data from smartphones, tablets, PCs and laptops. It also means seamless backups and easy access for employees or customers.

Answer (score 1):

2 excellent solutions:

1. [**OsmAnd**](http://osmand.net/) or [in GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=fr_FR) which is an excellent App which allow you to download OSM maps for all the world in vector format... so it is very useful (to find place by name for example) and you can have mountain shadow, elevation lines, etc.
   You can easily also register waypoint or tracks which are saved in GPX. GPX tracks or points can also be load and visible on maps... It is very useful app.

[image: OsmAnd on tablet]
[image: OsmAnd on smartphone]
[image: Example to find a POI]
[image: Some options which can be activate]

2. [**CyberTracker**](http://cybertracker.org/) and the associated [Wiki](http://cybertrackerwiki.org/) which allow you to create personalised forms to collect easily data with mobile devise, especially with Windows Mobile and Android. It is very stable. You design your form on your computer, then, you deploy it on mobile devises. It allow you to collect informations, take picture, register voice, register point or tracks. Then, data can be upload directly through FTP or by usb cable. Users can upload and see data on their own computers without be able to modify the apps (so it is safe). Data can be connected with database (MicrosoftSQL server, Microsoft Access or MySQL).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my own app here for completeness sake (although I may be biased :) ):

[**GPS Benchmark**](http://www.gpsbenchmark.com/)

It's the only app on Google Play that automatically compares a *user-entered* ground truth location to GPS data from the mobile device to calculate *true* accuracy of the GPS.  Other apps will only show the *estimated* location error that is calculated by the device, which (as GPS Benchmark shows) can be far from accurate.

While setting a ground truth location via tapping on the map is convenient, it can be limiting in terms of accuracy and precision. The app also supports typing in a known ground truth location lat/long/alt, which bypasses any potential map issues. To make manual entry less cumbersome, it also supports capturing a "geo:"-encoded location from a QR Code (encoded with a QR Code generator such as [ZXing](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/)) or NFC tag, which can be written using any NFC tag reader (including an option in GPS Benchmark to write the current ground truth location to an NFC tag).

GPS Benchmark exports the data as well as the results to KML and CSV formats, which are both compatible with ArcGIS products, as well as other GIS products.

The first image below is a screenshot of the GPS Benchmark app collecting data and calculating true error, and the second image is a screenshot of the results (green = 95th percentile, yellow is 68th percentile, and red is 50th percentile of horizontal error) being visualized in Google Earth.

[image: Screenshot of GPS Benchmark mobile app that measures GPS accuracy]

[image: Screenshot of GPS Benchmark output in Google Earth]

Link on Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gpsbenchmark.android

Answer (score 0):

We developed a new service for mobile GIS on tablets called GIS 2go ([www.gis2go.com](http://www.gis2go.com)). It includes an native app for tablets (Android or iPads) as well as an add-in for ArcGIS to prepare your maps for use in the app.

It allows also offline-use of the maps.

While on the go, you can as well redline, make notes, photos etc. and sync you notes back to ArcGIS.

You can download the app and the add-in from the website [www.gis2go.com](http://www.gis2go.com). A free demo-account is also available.

[image]