# List of GIS applications for Android OS

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIS Apps for Android Tablets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/gis-apps-for-android-tablets)

Do you know any GIS applications for android OS?

I can recommend following ones:

[Locus](https://market.android.com/details?id=menion.android.locus&hl=pl) - it is equivalent of GPS tourist navigation

[Shape file viewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=air.nexti.android.shpviewer) - it is .shp .dbf reader

[Arc Gis](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.esri.android.client&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3JpLmFuZHJvaWQuY2xpZW50Il0.)

It is also seems that [Quantum GIS](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/android-qgis/Tested_Devices) is starting to test for some devices.