# Alternatives to Google Maps on an Android phone

Tags: openstreetmap, android, google

An Android phone has Google Maps as its stock/default maps, POI and navigation app. What are other options that I have which can be used instead of Google Maps?

One obvious answer is [OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand&hl=en). OsmAnd has some cool features and also offline POI search and navigation.

Similarly from the talks in 2013 SOTM I discovered [Hikar](https://github.com/nickw1/Freemap/tree/master/java/hikar) which has some cool integration of routing and augmented reality.

What other such apps are out there?

I know that there is a [similar post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets) for Android, but the list there is mainly for data collection apps. I am curious about the application side. Apps that have simple map viewing POI search and query, routing and navigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of GIS applications for Android Tablets](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets)

Comment: I have already looked at the post, i don't think this is a duplicate. The question seeks for alternative to ArcGIS which is a full fledged GIS that includes data manipulation and data collection. I am trying to search for alternative to Google Maps which includes map viewing , POI queries and routing and navigation.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, but it seems to me that the other list offers a large list of apps that also answer your question directly.  While you are correct, there are a number of "full ArcGIS alternatives" in that question, there are also a number of alternatives for simple mapping (as you described) also included in that list.

Comment: But the two examples i mentioned above like OSMAnd and Hikar do not fit as answers to the question above and these are exactly the kind of apps that i was curious to know about, Thank you for retracting your close vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, most people say OsmAnd is the best for Android. Lacking further details, I can't judge on **your particular case**. You need to know what features you want:

- an app for end users or for mappers?
- support for smartphone or tablet?
- online or (fully) offline?
- routing with different profiles?
- POI search, address lookup?
- open source / free / commercial app?

With these **requirements**, you can filter this list: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android
So I can only post what seems to be **popular in the community**:

- [ForeverMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ForeverMap)
- [Gosmore](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore)
- [Komoot](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Komoot_for_Android)
- [Locus](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Locus)
- [mapFactor Free](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapFactor_Navigator_Free)
- [Navdroid](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/NavDroyd)
- [Navit](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit) / [Zanavi](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ZANavi)

Hope this will help! If not, feel free to post more details on your use case :)

Answer (score 8):

[Maps.me](https://maps.me/download/) has map viewing POI search and query, routing and navigation, and it can be used offline. Data is updated frequently and it is available for Android and iOS.

Comment: I was under the impression this was for iOS only... but if it is available for Android Maps.me is great!

Answer (score 2):

You could try [MapsWithMe](http://mapswith.me/en/home). It uses maps based on OpenStreetMap, and allows downloading complete countries for offline use. There is a free 'Lite' version, or a 'Pro' version for about $5. The pro version allows searching, and marking bookmarks.

Compared to OsmAnd it doesn't have as many features, eg it doesn't do routing, or recording a GPS track. But in my experience it is much easier to use, and quicker for browsing and zooming around the map.

Answer (score 1):

I just added an OSM wiki page for [OpenTripPlanner for Android](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/OpenTripPlanner-for-Android/wiki):
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenTripPlanner_(Android)

I don't know how long it will take to auto-populate the table in Mapper's response on the OSM wiki, so I'm posting here as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding, but please check the article again, there seem to be some minor markup problems :)  

I was never aware the OTP is a research project. So if you like, just add it here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Research

Comment: Thanks!  Fixed the markup issues :).  I'll take a look at the research page and see if I can find a good place to fit OTP.

Answer (score -1):

[umappin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mdiss.umappin) is a social network app.