# Maintaining list of GIS applications in mobile ecosystem as Github page?

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile-gis

I recently, read the post [Choosing Mobile GIS applications for Android Tablets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets)

I have seen a Github repository page https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books used for a similar purpose.

Is there a Github repository page for maintaining a list of GIS in mobile ecosystem (i.e., Android, iOS, Windows Phone, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

When I [searched GitHub for Mobile GIS repositories](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mobile%20gis) I found 59 but none appear to be what you are after.

If you wish to commence one at GitHub, and assuming that site allows you to, then I think that would be a more suitable place to maintain it than on this Stack Exchange site which promotes focussed Q&A, closes new list questions, and locks old list questions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Github repository [GIS-Geographic-Information-Systems-Mobile-Applications-list](https://github.com/akarsh/GIS-Geographic-Information-Systems-Mobile-Applications-list) after not finding any matches to the requirement of crowdsourced GIS mobile application list through 59 search results by the user [PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo) & my own search results in Github using keywords like mobile GIS list, others.